# Is there a way to write a Postgres query to select all rows that two columns are the same after removing everything after the dash?

Tags: regex, database, postgresql

I wanted to see if I could get some help with a PostgreSQL query I am trying to update:

```
 SELECT games.* 
 FROM games 
 INNER JOIN games_players 
   ON games.id = games_players.game_id 
 WHERE games.status = 'closed' 
 AND games_players.player_id = $1 
 AND games.away ~* '/.+?(?=-)/' <--- attempt at REGEX pattern match 
 ORDER BY scheduled DESC 
 LIMIT 5
```

I need to edit this query to only return the last 5 rows with existing conditions, but I also only want to return rows in that 'games' table that contain the same course name in the away column. Those column strings look like this: "TPC Four Seasons - RD 1". I attempted to do this above with a REGEX, but it does not seem to work and returns 0 rows. I would like to return the last 5 rows ordered by the scheduled column in descending order and also constrained to a regex for the away columns with matching substring before that "-" in the string. Is this possible and would anyone be able to help?

Update:

Additional attempt at query:

```
SELECT games.* 
FROM games 
INNER JOIN games_players ON games.id = games_players.game_id 
WHERE SUBSTRING(games.away, 0, STRPOS('-', games.away)) IN 
(
 SELECT SUBSTRING(games.away, 0, STRPOS('-', games.away)) FROM games 
 GROUP BY SUBSTRING(games.away, 0, STRPOS('-', games.away)) 
 HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
) 
AND games.status = 'closed' AND games_players.player_id = $1 
ORDER BY scheduled DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Rephrase the requirement as *two columns are the same after removing everything after the dash*, for which the easiest way is

```
regexp_replace(games.away, '-.*', '')
```

which matches a dash and everything following with nothing (effectively deleting it)

Putting that into the query:

```
SELECT distinct games.* 
FROM games
JOIN games g2 on regexp_replace(games.away, '-.*', '') = regexp_replace(g2.away, '-.*', '')
  AND g2.id != games.id
JOIN games_players ON games.id = games_players.game_id
WHERE games.status = 'closed' 
AND games_players.player_id = $1 
ORDER BY scheduled DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

---

BTW those slash characters in your regex match the character `/`, which is not what you want. *Some* languages (eg JavaScript) use the slash to *delimit* regexes, but slashes have no special meaning in regex.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much! This seems very close. I think the issue is that games_players table has no away column unfortunately. Just the following:

id,
game_id,
player_id

 scany: query multiple result rows: ERROR: column games_players.away does not exist (SQLSTATE 42703)

Comment: Is there a way to alter that boolean comparison with the regexp_replace() to look at the other rows in the games table?

Comment: @kor sure. What are the details of column names etc?

Comment: So the games table has:

id, league, status, home, away, season, scheduled, created_at, updated_at, description, home_id, away_id

Comment: And games_players table has: id, game_id, player_id

Comment: I edited the original post with another attempt, but it doesn't seem to be working properly entirely

Comment: Do you want to find games for a player (with id in variable `$1`) that have the same prefix of `away` as another game? See edits.

Comment: Yup! That's exactly what I want! It's so close to working, but for some reason it isn't returning all 4 rows with TPC Four Seasons as the course name prefix, only first three. And also returning an entirely different course name prefix as well.

Comment: Visit http://sqlfiddle.com, create the schema and insert data that illustrates your situation - an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  - then paste the link into your question .

Comment: Hey Bohemian! Thanks so much for your help, it definitely got me on the right path and was nearly there! I refined it some and posted the final result in the original post.

Comment: @kor it’s great that you figured out a solution, but please don’t put your solution in your question. Instead, post it as an answer! It’s perfectly OK to answer your own question, and even [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it. Doing so means future visitors can more easily find your solution and benefit from your good work.

Comment: Gotcha! i'll edit that

Answer (score 1):

I kept playing with the logic and doing inner selects to drill down to the info I needed and ended up getting the following correct result from this query:

```
select games.* 
FROM games 
INNER JOIN games_players ON games.id = games_players.game_id 
WHERE games.status = 'closed' AND 
games_players.player_id = $1 and
games.away LIKE concat(regexp_replace((select games.away FROM games ORDER BY scheduled DESC LIMIT 1 ), '-.*', ''), '%') 
ORDER BY scheduled desc
limit 5
```